# Reduce numbers of queries in OpenTSDB

Tags: opentsdb

I used opentsdb to save my time series data. Of each data point input, I must get 20 value of data points before. But, I have a large numbers of metrics, I can not call query opentsdb api too many times. How can I do to reduce numbers of query from openTSDB?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't aggregate different metrics into one single result. But I would suggest two solutions:

1. You can put multiple metrics queries in one call. If you use HTTP
   API endpoint you can do something like this:

   `http://otsdb:4242/api/query?start=15m-ago&m=avg:metric1{tag1=a}&m=avg:metric2{tag2=b}`

   You get the results for all queries with the same start(end) dates/times. But with multiple metrics don't forget that it will take longer time...
2. Redefine your time series.I don't know any details about your data, but if you're going to store and use data you should also think about usage - What queries am I going to use? How often? What would be the most common access to the data? And so on...

   That's also what's advised from OpenTSDB documentation [[1]](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing/index.html):

   > Cardinality also affects query speed a great deal, so consider the queries you will be performing frequently and optimize your naming schema for those.

   So, I would suggest to use tags to overcome this issue of multiple metrics. But as I mentioned I don't know your schema, but OpenTSDB is much more powerful with tags - there are many [examples](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/examples.html) and also [filtering options](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/filters.html) as well.

Edit 1:

From OpenTSDB 2.3 version there is also expression api: http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/exp.html

You should be able to handle multiple metric queries together (but I've never used that for any query).